# Шейдеры. Смена всех цветов на экране

Tags: c#, unity3d, шейдеры

Есть большое количество цветов. Нужно одновременно поменять абсолютно все цвета(и сделать это не один раз). Можно ли это сделать без получения компонента SpriteRenderer, ибо слишком много объектов? То есть по сути сместить всю палитру цветов, которую видит игрок, в какую-то сторону(включая фон камеры)? Вроде бы, мне в этом могут помочь шейдеры, дайте совет куда копать, если есть что-то на уме. Пытался найти сам, но то, что нужно не нашел. [image: Вот примерное такие цвета]

Comment: а почему Вас смущает множество объектов? через шейдеры это конечно можно решить, но не уверен что это будет то что Вам нужно

Comment: На объекте висит скрипт, который меняет его цвет. Условно, с белого на красный, с красного на черный и с черного на белый и так по кругу. И вот я хотел как то создать представление, будто цвет меняется не три раза, а куда больше раз. Есть вариант добавить еще цвета, но на данный момент цветов на экране и так много, и я просто не найду отличающиеся цвета.

Comment: Это некий визуальный эффект перемешивания?

Comment: друг предложил слово "инверсия", но перемешивание, по сути, да

Comment: и тем не менее скриптом это сделать будет проще

Comment: хорошо, вас понял. Спасибо